# How can I get wordpress page content without html tags?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

```
$content = get_the_content(); 
var_dump($content);
<figure class="wp-block-gallery columns-1 is-cropped"><ul class="blocks-gallery-grid"><li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src="http://www.frizon.rs/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/veliki-frizider.jpg" alt="" data-id="67" data-full-url="http://www.frizon.rs/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/veliki-frizider.jpg" data-link="http://www.frizon.rs/veliki-frizider/" class="wp-image-67"/></figure></li></ul></figure>
```

This is what I get from my page and i can't make some changes.

Comment: can you share the code in `get_the_content()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use wp_strip_all_tags function** [wp_strip_all_tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/)

```
wp_strip_all_tags( $content );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answer, now i get only paragrapf content. I lost media links. Is there some else function? It would be great if I can get all content in array, so i can make some other changes